# My SQL on client machine

Tags: java, mysql

I m deploying java desktop  application on client machine.used mysql database,
how to connect to database without install any environment  on client machine ?

Comment: do you mean like, as you bought the box, as is, from BestBuy ?

Comment: You must ship/deliver your client (desktop) application with the JDBC driver (assuming you are NOT using ODBC) for MySQL...that's it!

Answer (score 1):

You must ship/deliver your client (desktop) application with the JDBC driver (assuming you are NOT using ODBC) for MySQL...that's it!

**UPDATE**

Of course, make sure it is available in the Java classpath.

Comment: i'm using jdbc driver of my sql  but how  to  connect to database on client machine?

Comment: You need to copy the JAR file (MySQL driver) in the Java classpath

Comment: without set up mysql on client device?

Comment: What do you mean with "MySQL on client device"? I assume you are trying to install the server in the client itself. But that really transparent to your client (desktop) application, since it only needs that proper JDBC URL; but yes, you can also use MySQL (server) in the client machine